# CKEditor in Angular. TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null after insertText

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm building an app in which I'm using CKEditor inside of Angular framework.

Anyway - everything is working but when I'm trying to call the function insertText I have the following error:

> edit.html:180
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
>       at a (ckeditor.js:139)
>       at CKEDITOR.dom.range.createBookmark2 (ckeditor.js:141)
>       at Array.createBookmarks2 (ckeditor.js:487)
>       at CKEDITOR.dom.selection.createBookmarks2 (ckeditor.js:440)
>       at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.Image (ckeditor.js:1081)
>       at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.UndoManager.save (ckeditor.js:1076)
>       at a. (ckeditor.js:1072)
>       at a.m (ckeditor.js:10)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13) View_PageEditComponent_3 @ edit.html:180 DebugContext_.logError @
>   services.ts:571 ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.ts:69 next @
>   application_ref.ts:366 schedulerFn @ event_emitter.ts:96
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:252 SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.ts:204 Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135 Subscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.ts:95 Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61 EventEmitter.emit @
>   event_emitter.ts:78 NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.ts:87 onHandleError
>   @ ng_zone.ts:283 ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:385 Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:184 ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476
>
> ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 137, nodeDef:
>   Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}component:
>   (...)componentRenderElement: (...)context: (...)elDef:
>   ObjectelOrCompView: (...)elView: Objectinjector: (...)nodeDef:
>   ObjectnodeIndex: 137providerTokens: (...)references: (...)renderNode:
>   (...)view: Object__proto__: Objectcomponent:
>   (...)componentRenderElement: (...)context: (...)elOrCompView:
>   (...)injector: (...)logError: function (console)providerTokens:
>   (...)references: (...)renderNode: (...)constructor: function
>   DebugContext_(view, nodeIndex)get component: function ()get
>   componentRenderElement: function ()get context: function ()get
>   elOrCompView: function ()get injector: function ()get providerTokens:
>   function ()get references: function ()get renderNode: function
>   ()**proto**: Object View_PageEditComponent_3 @ edit.html:180
>   DebugContext_.logError @ services.ts:571 ErrorHandler.handleError @
>   error_handler.ts:69 next @ application_ref.ts:366 schedulerFn @
>   event_emitter.ts:96 SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:252
>   SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:204 Subscriber._next @
>   Subscriber.ts:135 Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95 Subject.next @
>   Subject.ts:61 EventEmitter.emit @ event_emitter.ts:78
>   NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.ts:87 onHandleError @ ng_zone.ts:283
>   ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:385 Zone.runTask @ zone.js:184
>   ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476

Here's my CKEditor selector:

```
<ckeditor
        name="content"
        id="content"
        [(ngModel)]="page.content"
        debounce="500"
        [config]="{
                                                skins: 'minimalist',
                                                allowedContent: true,
                                                extraPlugins: 'divarea',
                                                contentsCss: CKECSS
                                            }"
        (ready)="setCkeObject($event)"
        (focus)="setCkeObject($event)"
        (blur)="setCkeObject($event)"
        #ckeEditor
>
</ckeditor>
```

And parts of my editComponent TypeScript:

```
setCkeObject($event) {
        this.ckeObject = $event;
    }

insert_shortcode(shortcode) {
        if (this.ckeObject != null && this.ckeObject.editor != null) {
            this.ckeObject.editor.insertText(shortcode);
            this.alertService.addAlert('success', 'alerts.file_added_at_the_content_cursor_position');
        } else {
            this.page.content += shortcode;
            this.alertService.addAlert('warning', 'alerts.sorry_something_gone_wrong');
        }
    }
```

The thing is that sometimes it's working propley and sometimes it dosn't.

The bit of code from ckeditor.js that's causing this issue (line 6):

```
createBookmark2: function() {
                function a(b) {
                    var e = b.container, d = b.offset, f;
                    f = e;
                    var g = d;
                    f = f.type != CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT || 0 === g || g == f.getChildCount() ? 0 : f.getChild(g - 1).type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT && f.getChild(g).type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT;
                    f && (e = e.getChild(d - 1),
                    d = e.getLength());
                    if (e.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && 0 < d) {
                        a: {
                            for (f = e; d--; )
                                if (g = f.getChild(d).getIndex(!0),
                                0 <= g) {
                                    d = g;
                                    break a
                                }
                            d = -1
                        }
                        d += 1
                    }
                    if (e.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT) {
                        f = e;
                        for (g = 0; (f = f.getPrevious()) && f.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT; )
                            g += f.getText().replace(CKEDITOR.dom.selection.FILLING_CHAR_SEQUENCE, "").length;
                        f = g;
                        e.getText() ? d += f : (g = e.getPrevious(c),
                        f ? (d = f,
                        e = g ? g.getNext() : e.getParent().getFirst()) : (e = e.getParent(),
                        d = g ? g.getIndex(!0) + 1 : 0))
                    }
                    b.container = e;
                    b.offset = d
                }
                function b(a, c) {
                    var e = c.getCustomData("cke-fillingChar");
                    if (e) {
                        var d = a.container;
                        e.equals(d) && (a.offset -= CKEDITOR.dom.selection.FILLING_CHAR_SEQUENCE.length,
                        0 >= a.offset && (a.offset = d.getIndex(),
                        a.container = d.getParent()))
                    }
                }
                var c = CKEDITOR.dom.walker.nodeType(CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT, !0);
                return function(c) {
                    var d = this.collapsed
                      , f = {
                        container: this.startContainer,
                        offset: this.startOffset
                    }
                      , g = {
                        container: this.endContainer,
                        offset: this.endOffset
                    };
                    c && (a(f),
                    b(f, this.root),
                    d || (a(g),
                    b(g, this.root)));
                    return {
                        start: f.container.getAddress(c),
                        end: d ? null : g.container.getAddress(c),
                        startOffset: f.offset,
                        endOffset: g.offset,
                        normalized: c,
                        collapsed: d,
                        is2: !0
                    }
                }
            }(),
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it by amending the selector and setting the CKEditor object only once when it's ready.

```
<ckeditor
        name="content"
        id="content"
        [(ngModel)]="page.content"
        debounce="500"
        [config]="{
                                                skins: 'minimalist',
                                                allowedContent: true,
                                                extraPlugins: 'divarea',
                                                contentsCss: CKECSS
                                            }"
        (ready)="setCkeObject($event)"
        #ckeEditor
>
</ckeditor>
```